# How can I get the value from XML tree?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, xml

I am trying to get a value of `legalName` and `phyCity`

from this link: [check](https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/44110.xml?webKey=dadd9237da5c0390c9511ef871258e1703abdb36)

And I want to use JavaScript as I wrote below:

```
$('.DotNum').click(function (e) {
        var dotNum = $('#DotNum').val().replace(/\-|\s/g, '');
        var url = "https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/"+ dotNum +".xml?webKey=dadd9237da5c0390c9511ef871258e1703abdb36";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
                var legalName = xmlDoc.nodeValue("response").ChildNode("content").ChildNode("carrier").attribute("legalName");
                $('#CompName').val(legalName);
                $('#CompCity').val(phyCity);
                $('#CompState').val(state);
                $('#CompAddress').val(address);
            }
        }
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    });
```

I don't know how to get the value of `legalName`
So I tried many different things...

How can I do `var legalName = xmlDoc.brabrabar`

Comment: What is expected result of `var legalName = xmlDoc.nodeValue("response").ChildNode("content").ChildNode("carrier").attribute("legalName");`?
`

Comment: @guest271314 not working.. it is null

Comment: Please include an example of the XML returned by that service, that you want to interact with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.getElementsByTagName()` to get the element you seek:

```
var carrier = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('carrier')[0];
var legalName = carrier.getAttribute('legalName');
var phyCity = carrier.getAttribute('phyCity');
var state = carrier.getAttribute('phyState');
```

**Working example:**

```js
function queryDot(dotNum) {
  var url = "https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/" + dotNum + ".xml?webKey=dadd9237da5c0390c9511ef871258e1703abdb36";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;

      var carrier = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('carrier')[0];

      var legalName = carrier.getAttribute('legalName');
      var phyCity = carrier.getAttribute('phyCity');
      var state = carrier.getAttribute('phyState');

      console.log(legalName, phyCity, state);
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send(null);
}

queryDot(44110);
```

Since you appear to be using jQuery, you could also do this the jQuery way:

```js
function queryDot(dotNum) {
  $.get("https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/" + dotNum + ".xml?webKey=dadd9237da5c0390c9511ef871258e1703abdb36")
    .then(function(result) {
      var carrier = $(result).find('carrier');

      var legalName = carrier.attr('legalName');
      var phyCity = carrier.attr('phyCity');
      var state = carrier.attr('phyState');

      console.log(legalName, phyCity, state);
    });
}

queryDot(44110);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

xmlDoc.nodeValue() function will return string.

Instead of this you can use, xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("carrier")

This will return an array of nodes. If you are sure you have only one node then you can access directly as [0] index otherwise loop and get the attribute value by using getAttribute('');

Comment: Hey, okay you use it as .nodeValue("response") which will return string.

Hence try accessing the xml node directly like xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('carrier')[0].getAttribute('legalName')

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: Sure sure,

xmlDoc.nodeValue() function will return string. Instead of this you can use, 

xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("carrier") this will return an array of nodes.

if you are sure you have only one node then you can access directly as [0] index otherwise loop and get the attribute value by using

getAttribute('<attributename>');

Comment: In the answer itself, not as a comment.